# ng-repeat updates all the form

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to do kind of a cart in IONIC ( I'm new using this framework as well ).
I have a ng-repeat to fill my screen with products from the database (firebase), inside this ng-repeat I have a form.
My form contais 3 elements, an  an  and a button. When I fill my form and press add. it works fine. but if I add a second product, my first one gets updated with the value of the new one. Exemple:

1) Add a product A. Qtd: 3 unity: mg.
2) Add a product B. Qtd: 8 utity: g.

Then my first product turn into:   product A. Qtd: 8 unity: m8.

Some one can please help me?

Following my HTML and my JS

```js
$scope.category = Category.name;   
    $scope.amount = {count: '', unit: 'mg'};

    function AddToCart(product, amount)
    {
        if(amount.count == null)
            return;
        
        if(!$rootScope.cart)
          $rootScope.cart = [];

        $rootScope.cart.push({
            item: product,
            qtd: amount
        });

        showToast();
    }
```

```html
<div class="item item-product" id="{{$index}}-item" ng-repeat="item in vm.Products | filter:filter.product" >
                <p style="width: 95%; margin: 0;">{{item.name}}</p>
                <button class="arrow-button" ng-click="showDetails($index)" sytle = "border: none; width: 100%;"><i class="icon ion-ios-arrow-right"></i></button>
                <div class="details" id ="{{$index}}-details" style="z-index: 999;">
                    <hr>
                    <p> {{item.about}}</p>
                    <form class="cart-area" id ="{{$index}}-form" ng-submit="vm.AddToCart(item, amount,$index)">
                        <input type="number" id = "{{$index}}-input" ng-model="amount.count" placeholder="Qtd">
                        <div class="list">
                            <select ng-model="amount.unit">
                                <option>mg</option>
                                <option selected>g</option>
                                <option>kg</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <button><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>Adicionar cotação</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: No I didn't, can you send me a link ?

Comment: after looking deeper into it, ng-form will help, but it's not the underlying issue you have. You have the quantities and categories bound to a single value that is pointed to by each item in the ng-repeat. So, by nature of the two-way binding of `ng-model`, when you update one, it updates the source variable, which then updates all of the other elements pointing to it. I will try to come up with a demo of how you can do this instead

Comment: Okay, thanks for helping. I'm struggling a lot with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so you were on the right track, but didn't quite understand how to bind the controls to a specific product - you were binding them to a shared scope, which is why when you updated one, you updated all of them. That is the nature of the two-way data binding built in to AngularJS.

What you want to do is bind the ng-model value to a property on the item itself, like so:

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", [])
  .controller("myCtrl", ["$scope",
    function($scope) {
      var $this = this;
      $this.Products = [{
        name: "Product 1",
        about: "Info About Product 1",
        count: 3,
        unit: "mg"
      }, {
        name: "Product 2",
        about: "Info About Product 2",
        count: 8,
        unit: "g"
      }, {
        name: "Product 3",
        about: "Info About Product 3",
        count: 2,
        unit: "kg"
      }, ];
    }
  ]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl as vm">
  <h3>Solution using properties on Products</h3>
  <div class="item item-product" id="{{$index}}-item" ng-repeat="item in vm.Products | filter:filter.product">
    <p style="width: 95%; margin: 0;">{{item.name}}</p>
    <div class="details" id="{{$index}}-details" style="z-index: 999;">
      <hr>
      <p>{{item.about}}</p>
      <div ng-form="{{$index}}-form" class="cart-area" ng-submit="vm.AddToCart(item, amount,$index)">
        <input type="number" ng-model="item.count" placeholder="Qtd">
        <div class="list">
          <select ng-model="item.unit">
            <option value="mg">mg</option>
            <option value="g">g</option>
            <option value="kg">kg</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <button><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>Adicionar cotação</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try it here

Comment: @LucasGaspar You're welcome, glad it worked for you =)